# Data File Handling - find count of word in file

Tags: c++, c++11, data-files

I have this Homework question:

> Write a function in C++ to count the presence of a word '*do*' in a text file.

#### What I have tried:

I tried to first search the word '*d*' in the text file, then search for '*o*' if present just after it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::fstream;
using std::cout;
using std::ios;

int main()
{
    char ch[10];
    int count=0, a=0;
    fstream f;
    f.open("P.txt", ios::in);

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.get(ch)
        if (ch[a]=='d')
        {
            if ((a++)=='o')
                count++;
        } 
        a++;
    }
    cout << "the no of do's is" << count;
    f.close();
}
```

but this idea is completely useless. I cannot think of any other ideas. I would love to have a **Hint** regarding this in two scenarios:

1.count the word 'do' independently existing.

2.count the word 'do' present anywhere in the text.

this is a data file handling question.

Comment: Why don't ya'll post some code, darn tootin'?

Comment: Ask question with your code (you must have) is always a good thing here.

Comment: OK I WILL EDIT IT

Comment: Reading file line-by-line with [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and using [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)? Or even better: reading the file word-by-word (`inFile >> str;`), and counting occurrences of a word.

Comment: @callyalater i have edited

Comment: @appleapple please see

Comment: i am new to this site please don't let me blocked for forever.

Comment: @em1382 i have posted the code

Comment: oh...thanks i am blocked.i regret for my  mistake.(sorry i won't commit this in future again sorry.) please do something.

Comment: The downvotes hit hard on this question. Ouch.

Comment: @Jinx88909 no...... i am really so000000rrrrrrryyyyyyy.

Comment: @PushkarSoni You are checking if `(a++)=='0'`, but `a` is declared as an `int` and has no relationship to what is actually stored in the `char` array.

Comment: @callyalater thankyou very much.

Comment: isn't it `'o'` instead of `'0'`?

Comment: @appleapple yes

Comment: you never initialize the `count` and it can be anything.

Comment: i am going to cry...now :(:(:(

Comment: do you want `"dodo"` to be 2 count?

Comment: @appleapple yes and no both

Comment: ok thanks now guys I will quit. no other solution

Comment: You cannot say both, they have different algorithm. Or are you telling us you   don't even try to understand your **homework** and waste our time?

Comment: does any one have suggestion on where to study, i mean where to find questions and answers my book doesn't contain these answers only question and finding answers is difficult self study is hard

Comment: @appleapple noooo...... i mean that i want to know algorithms for both.

Comment: @appleapple will you help? however you can quit , i have no hope left.

Comment: @appleapple i am blocked!

Comment: @PushkarSoni chill out. You have asked for a homework question to be answered and originally didn't show any code. The point of homework is to do it yourself however it's fine to place on here as long as you show you've tried and what it is you have tried. You've been blocked because of a poor question (probably) however some have retracted their downvotes (since the edit now shows code). You need to clearly define what it is you're after and what it is you have tried in future. Your original question attracted downvotes which it should, it was terrible. The system does the blocking, not us.

Comment: @PushkarSoni well, I can not help you, as you can see, I have no privileges on that (I even don't know one can be blocked). BTW, the downvotes is not mine.

Comment: @appleapple no....i will never mind the downvotes. i am very sorryyyy. but i only want people leave this question , i am new and don't want to be blocked on my first day. i am not a troll but a student. y punish so hard?

Comment: Some hint, you probably need `string s;cin>>s;` for "dodo" -> 0. And `char c;cin.get(c);` for "dodo" -> 2.

Comment: @PushkarSoni it's what people do. I didn't downvote. On the plus, I upvoted since I thought the question was valid (after the edits). You're very lucky someone has answered the question for you however. This is a professional site and you've come across quite unprofessional with the comments. Take the time to thank them and understand what they have done. I understand their is a learning curve but it's you who has to learn so hit the Internet and get looking :) happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm follows from what you have. Structure your while-loop like this:

```
while(!fin.eof()) {
    bool found = false;    
    do {
        fin.get(ch);
        found = found || ch == 'd';
    } while (ch == 'd' && fin);

    if (found && ch == 'o') {
        // boom goes the dynamite
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `do-while` is to eliminate repeating `d`'s, so that after that loop, you simply check if the next character is `o`.

### Note

- In terms of typing, the type for `ch` should be `char ch`

### Explained

- `while(!fin.eof())`

  - Repeat the next few lines until we reach the end of the file
- `do {`

  - Beginning of a `do-while` loop
- `fin.get(ch);`

  - Read a single byte (character) from the file
- `found = found || ch == 'd';`

  - Set `found` to true if we have already found a `d` or the current character is a `d`
- `} while (ch == 'd' && fin);`

  - End of `do-while`. Repeat the loop until the last character read is not a `d` or we have reached the end of the file
- `if (found && ch == 'o') {`

  - If we were able to satisfy the condition for setting `found` to true and the last character we read is `o`...
- `// boom goes the dynamite`

  - then we have successfully found the word `do`

### Sans [`std::ios::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof)

I won't explain this next bit, but it will follow closely with what I already posted. The goal here is to protect yourself from reading an already empty file.

```
while(fin >> ch) {
    while(ch == 'd' && fin.get(ch)) {    
        if (ch != 'd') {
            if (ch != 'o') {
                break;
            }
            // Found it!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but i am a kid (17') and i couldn't understand the code.

Comment: @PushkarSoni Age has nothing to do it. I was posting on SO when I was 17, but I knew the difference between a good question and begging to have something handed to you.

Comment: @PushkarSoni Code explained

Comment: If you're going to suggest how to read a file, you might as well do it correctly, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: actually i want to count no of 'do's in the file.

Comment: @PushkarSoni You will have to provide further explanation if you want to get anymore meaningful answers. The code I have above can be used to find the word `do`

Comment: @smac89 exactly. but i want to count no of do's present in the file E.g. "doafdo do do.dfdo.do" then the program should give output - 6

Comment: @smac89 actually i wasn't able to understand       found = found || ch == 'd'; but now i understood.